# form input minlength is not working after onKeyup Event

Tags: html

`<label for="prenum">preNumber</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prenum" onKeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^-0-9]/g,'');" minlength='6' maxlength="6" required>`

hello.
As the title says, minlength doesn't work after the onKeyup event.
Any solution?

Create an input tag that validates correctly when only 6 digits are entered

Comment: I solved it.
pattern=".{6,6}"
Added it and it works!

Comment: The dot `.` matches _any_ character, not just digits. The character class for digits is `\d`, so your pattern should look like this: `\d{6,6}`